# Grub2 cannot detect the filesystem of a second system partition. Instant reboot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, reboot, ext4

So here is the situation:

I am running 14.04 LTS and installed 17.10 on a separate partition for testing purposes. Before installation, I resized a scratch partition to make space for the new system using GParted (and left the empty space as "free space"). I did install 17.10 to the newly available space (creating an ext4 partition) and did **NOT** install a 2nd bootloader (ubiquity -b option). The layout of my disk now looks as follows:

- sda1 - ext4 - 14.04 LTS
- sda2 - swap
- sda3 - ext4 - Scratch partition
- sda4 - ext4 - 17.10

Installation of 17.10 went fine and without any issues. Back in my 14.04 box, I ran

`sudo update-grub`

and the new system was successfully detected via os-prober and added to my grub.cfg.

Now, when I reboot and select the available 17.10 install from the grub menu the computer **instantly reboots** without any message at all.

So on the next boot I went to the grub console and looked for all available partions. When I use `ls` all partitions are detected:

`(hd0,gpt1), (hd0,gpt2), (hd0,gpt3), (hd0,gpt4)`

When using

`ls (hd0,gpt1)` or `ls (hd0,gpt3)`

I get the usual info about this partition - among other the filesystem of the partition, in this case ext4. However performing this on the new partition (hd0,gpt4) I get the message that the filesystem is unknown. So then I used a *Super Grub2 Disk* to start the system from there. Here the system does not reboot, but I get the error:

```
attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0
unknown filesystem
```

When I am in my 14.04 box however, the partition can be mounted without any issues and I can access all files etc.

A few things to the machine: This is a workstation I took over from a colleague so I did not set up the initial system. There is an LSI (mr9240-4i) hardware Raid 1 installed with 2 4TB drives. But I somehow doubt that this is the issue. Everything works as it should and in my 14.04 box only one drive is shown as it is supposed to.

Something else whicch made me wonder is, that the disk is partitioned using GPT. However there is no separate boot partition which I read was mandatory when using GPT with BIOS instead of UEFI (which is the case here).

So at this point I am very much lost and out of ideas how to debug this. Any help or hint in the right direction would be much appreciated!

I added the results of the Boot Info Script for further details:
[Boot Info Script](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26096076/)

EDIT: Added a foto of the error message Super Grub2 Disk gives me when selecting the new system install:

[Grub Fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVDpB.jpg)

Comment: I have seen one or two others without bios_grub, but I thought it was required. Grub can use blocklists which is considered un-reliable which may be the issue. I would add a bios_grub, it only needs to be 1 or 2MB anywhere on drive.Just shrink sda1 and insert unformatted 1MB partition with bios_grub flag. Or if using gdisk code ef02. Then reinstall grub-pc.  I normally suggest first two partitions be ESP & bios_grub on all new gpt drives. Then they can be used either UEFI or BIOS without major reformatting.  Not sure if that is issue or not. Older versions of grub had issues with large drives.

Comment: @oldfred, I did what you suggested. I inserted a small 2MB partition at the end of sda1 and formatted it to bios_grub (ef02). Then I re-installed grub `grub-install /dev/sda` with no error message. The old system still boots fine, unfortunately no change with the new partition. Grub is still not able to detect the gpt4 partiton filesystem. I did another boot info script [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26112480/) and als added a foto of the error message when using Super Grub2 Disk to the original post.

Comment: Your new report shows os-prober found the other install. See line 343.

Comment: I know. I never did not find it. I can also select 17.10 from the grub boot menu. But then the computer instantly reboots. This is why I did ask the question in the first place.

Comment: I do not know where the Super Grub error on UUID is coming from. You do not show that UUID anywhere, is that from Super Grub disk itself? I have seen where drive order gets changed when flash drive plugged in.From 14.04's grub can you use recovery mode on 17.10 install?

Comment: Its the UUID of sda4, see 2nd boot info script from 4 comments above, line 76. I did a re-install (and therfore reformated sda4) inbetween the first boot info script and the 2nd. Thats why the UUIDs differ. The odd thing is, that Super Grub2 Disk looks itself for bootable partitions without necessarily relying on the grub.cfg. But it cannot even read sda4. Same thing with the systems install of grub2. Could it be the disk size of 4TB thats somehow causing this? sda4 is at the very end of the disk.

Comment: Some old versions of grub when multiple TB drives came out could not read boot files beyond some size. But if UUID does not now exist due to reinstall, how even is Super-grub finding it? Something not updated internally and still has old UUID.

Comment: I did reinstall grub as well. So it should be able to read the file system of the partition.

Comment: If you installed originally on gpt without bios_grub it put a core.img into your Linux partition. Perhaps SuperGrub is finding that old core.img, not the new correct one in your bios_grub. Part of issue with blocklists and hard coded address, but then file is also still there.